# Error in starting postgresql service in linux through command line

Tags: linux, postgresql

I was starting the postgresql service by

```
systemctl start postgresql.service
```

It was raising an error as below

```
Job for postgresql.service failed. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xn" for details.
```

Please help how to start the service through command line in linux?

Output for journalctl -xn

```
 osboxes:/home/osboxes # journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Wed 2015-04-08 10:08:38 BST, end at Tue 2016-03-22  14:15:07 GMT. --
Mar 22 14:09:03 osboxes wickedd[824]: eno16777760: Notified neighbours   about IP address 192.168
Mar 22 14:09:03 osboxes wickedd[824]: route ipv4 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.182.2 dev eno16777760 ty
Mar 22 14:09:04 osboxes wickedd[824]: Skipping hostname update, none available
Mar 22 14:15:01 osboxes cron[9120]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root by (u
Mar 22 14:15:01 osboxes systemd[9121]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user 
Mar 22 14:15:01 osboxes CRON[9120]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
Mar 22 14:15:01 osboxes systemd[9122]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user 
Mar 22 14:15:07 osboxes postgresql[9160]: Initializing PostgreSQL 9.3.11 at location ~postgres/
Mar 22 14:15:07 osboxes postgresql[9160]: ..failed
Mar 22 14:15:07 osboxes postgresql[9160]: You can find a log of the initialisation in ~postgres
```

Comment: So, what does output the given command `systemctl status postgresql.service` ?

Comment: Start the PostgreSQL master daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/postgresql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-03-22 11:43:28 GMT; 3min 1s ago
   Process: 4609 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/postgresql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6807 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/postgresql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: ok, and `journalctl -xn` ?

Comment: Edited my post. The output is there in the post.

Comment: Did you find the log of the initialisation in `~postgres/` ?

Comment: Where could i find logs? any path?

Comment: As specified in the logs posted above; `You can find a log of the initialisation in ~postgres`. This means you will probably find a log file in the HOME directory of the postgres user.